# Blas GEMV launch failed: m=3, n=2 [Op:MatMul]

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, blas

When I run the following code, I get the error:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:654] failed to run cuBLAS routine cublasSgemv_v2: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "modelAndLayer.py", line 16, in <module>
y_pred=model(X)
File "/home/cxsbg/anaconda3/envs/dl36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 314, in __call__
output = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cxsbg/anaconda3/envs/dl36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 717, in __call__
outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "modelAndLayer.py", line 10, in call
output=self.dense(input)
File "/home/cxsbg/anaconda3/envs/dl36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 314, in __call__
output = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cxsbg/anaconda3/envs/dl36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 717, in __call__
outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cxsbg/anaconda3/envs/dl36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 163, in call
outputs = gen_math_ops.mat_mul(inputs, self.kernel)
File "/home/cxsbg/anaconda3/envs/dl36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 4305, in mat_mul
_six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMV launch failed:  m=3, n=2 [Op:MatMul]
```

My gpu is **RTX2080** and the driver is **v410**. The cuda is **v9.0**, the cudnn is **v7**. The tensorflow-gpu is **v1.8** (I tired on both v1.8 and v1.12). The python is **v3.6** (I tried on both v3.6 and v2.7). The system is **Ubuntu 16.04**  (I also tired on win10).

The problem always occurs on tensorflow-gpu, but it works on tensorflow cpu.

Code is here (a simple linear model):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
X=tf.constant([[1.,2.,3,],[4.,5.,6.]])
Y=tf.constant([[10.],[20.]])
class Linear(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense=tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,kernel_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    def call(self,input):
        output=self.dense(input)
        return output
model=Linear()
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3)
for i in range(1000):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred=model(X)
        loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_pred-Y))
    grads=tape.gradient(loss,model.variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,model.variables))
print(model.variables)
```

Comment: This is a bug report. You should file a tensorflow github issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is caused by the tf.enable_eager_execution() as I test it many times. Thanks to the author [which-version-of-cuda-can-work-with-rtx-2080](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042920/which-version-of-cuda-can-work-with-rtx-2080/). When I use cuda9.2, the error is fixed.